# Overlapping of features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, features

Does a simple way exist to draw overlapping zones in QGIS (3.22.3-Białowieża)?
The situation is the following. I have a join of the kind

ZoneA FeatA

ZoneB FeatB

ZoneC FeatC

ZoneD FeatA
an
ZoneD FeatC

where ZoneXs have been defined by a shapefile in a layer, and the table with FeatXs is joined as an attribute.
I would like to represent, for example, ZoneD with a theme (or pattern) deriving from the merge (or overlapping patterns) of FeatA and FeatC. At first glance, transparency does not work, because QGIS draws ZoneD with only one feature, and does not overlap the two modes.

Comment: This is rather unclear. Could you include a screenshot?

Comment: It seems you have a polygon shapefile with Zones and an attribute file with Feats and have joined these. But it is not clear what overlap you are trying to draw. I guess you have set categorised symbology for Feats and  ZoneD, having one to many join, shows up with only one of the symbols. Is this your problem?

Comment: If what I mentioned is your case, then `Layer Properties > Symbology > Layer Rendering> Blending Mode >Feature > Choose Overlay` might help.